# Error when trying to create many to many relationship in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a problem with Asp.Net when I'm trying to create a many to many relationship model, I get this error when trying to register an account :

> Sequence contains no matching element

When I "disabled" my changes, I could register on the site normally so there are some errors in my models regarding the column structure I suppose but I'm unable to fix them myself. I want to create a many to many connection between my `Bookmark` and `Tag` tables and the many-many table should have following structure: `Id`, `BookmarkID`, `TagID`.

Here are my models:

```
public class Bookmark
{   
    [Key]
    public int BookmarkID { get; set; }

    public string Url { get; set; }

    public ApplicationUser UserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BookmarkTag> BookmarkTags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int TagID { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName="varchar(60)")]
    public string TagName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<BookmarkTag> BookmarkTags { get; set; }
}

public class BookmarkTag
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int BookmarkTagID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int BookmarkID { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 2)]
    public int TagID { get; set; }

    public virtual Bookmark Bookmark { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get;  set;}
}
```

Here is the error stack trace as well:

> [InvalidOperationException: Sequence contains no matching element]
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Single(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>   +2603017    System.Data.Entity.Utilities.DbProviderManifestExtensions.GetStoreTypeFromName(DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest, String name) +81
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.ConfigureColumn(EdmProperty
>   column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest) +87
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(EdmProperty
>   column, EntityType table, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean
>   allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration) +138
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__3(Tuple`2
>   pm) +38
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Utilities.IEnumerableExtensions.Each(IEnumerable`1
>   ts, Action`1 action) +130
>
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Properties.Primitive.PrimitivePropertyConfiguration.Configure(IEnumerable`1
>   propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean
>   allowOverride, Boolean fillFromExistingConfiguration) +94
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.StructuralTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(IList`1
>   propertyMappings, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, Boolean
>   allowOverride) +154
>
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.ConfigurePropertyMappings(DbDatabaseMapping
>   databaseMapping, EntityType entityType, DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest, Boolean allowOverride) +585
>
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.Types.EntityTypeConfiguration.Configure(EntityType
>   entityType, DbDatabaseMapping databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest) +177
>
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.ConfigureEntityTypes(DbDatabaseMapping
>   databaseMapping, ICollection`1 entitySets, DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest) +423
>   System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Configuration.ModelConfiguration.Configure(DbDatabaseMapping
>   databaseMapping, DbProviderManifest providerManifest) +376
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbProviderManifest
>   providerManifest, DbProviderInfo providerInfo) +444
>   System.Data.Entity.DbModelBuilder.Build(DbConnection
>   providerConnection) +55
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.CreateModel(LazyInternalContext
>   internalContext) +61
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.RetryLazy`2.GetValue(TInput input) +123
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
>   +616    System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type
>   entityType) +18
>
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize() +53
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
>   +16    System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
>   +39    System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 predicate, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   +154    System.Data.Entity.QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(IQueryable`1
>   source, Expression`1 predicate) +163
>   Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.d__6c.MoveNext()
>   +472    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.CultureAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +59    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<ValidateUserName>d__4.MoveNext() +594    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<ValidateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
>   +266    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__0.MoveNext()
>   +568    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.<CreateAsync>d__d.MoveNext()
>   +483    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58    System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>   +28    BookIT.Controllers.d__15.MoveNext() in D:\Projekti\CS\BookIT\BookIT\Controllers\AccountController.cs:155
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) +99
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) +58
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.TaskAsyncActionDescriptor.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +97
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.b__36(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +17
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +32
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__3d()
>   +50    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.b__3f()
>   +225    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +34
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.b__1c()
>   +26    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +100
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +27
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1d(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__15(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +22
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +26
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +10
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__5(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) +29
>
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
>   +28    System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult
>   result) +9
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +9711525    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

Thanks in advance

Added:

```
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
```

Comment: Have you checked the InnerException message?

Comment: BTW you don't need BookmarkTagId in the composite keys in BookmarkTag. Just BookmarkId and TagId are sufficient.

Comment: Can you add the code that is actually throwing the error with these models?  Your stack trace indicates that it's around AccountController:155.  Based upon the exception text it looks like you're calling .Single() or .First() but we cannot know that without looking at the actual code.

Comment: Yes it's throwing the error at that exact line but i haven't changed anything in the code besides my own models that i put up there and when i remove those models the registration goes through... The rest of the code is the defualt when you create a new mvc program and check individual accounts option @CodeNotFound yeah i know i just put it there cause i want to add an extra column

Comment: @IvanRepusic then what is the predicate you give to your Single() or First() method?

Comment: @CodeNotFound what do you mean? I don't understand your question. As far as i know this is the process of registering an account so there should not be a first or single method involved

Comment: I mean maybe you are doing something like Single(p => [conditon or predicate] or Where(p => [condition or predicate]).Single() in your code somewhere. You must put in the question the query in cause.

Comment: The model is not correct  for at least many-to-many relationship.  I have given you examples of both one to many and many-to-many- http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You have too many Key attributes, the EF Framework cannot work out your model. You can use fluent api to configure exactly what you want. The easiest way you can solve your issue is to use EF feature Convention Over Configuration. Basically, follow the conventions and the EF Framework will do the heavy lifting for you. I have  added here a convention over configuration approach and it runs in at least in my visual studio. I have tested this and it runs successfully.

```
public class Bookmark
{
   public int BookmarkID { get; set; }
   public string Url { get; set; }
   public ApplicationUser UserId { get; set; }
   public virtual ICollection<BookmarkTag> BookmarkTags { get; set; }
 }

 public class BookmarkTag
 {
    public int BookmarkTagID { get; set; }
    public virtual Bookmark Bookmark { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
 }

 public class Tag
 {
    public int TagID { get; set; }
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BookmarkTag> BookmarkTags { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry for responding late but this also wont fix the problem i get the same error again

Answer (score 0):

In the end i found the reason that caused the error...
IT was this line

```
 [Column(TypeName="varchar(60)")]
public string TagName { get; set; }
```

Whene i removed the Column(TypeName) part the code went to compile without any problems... It works now but i'm not sure why it does or why did it throw that error. Can anyone explain why did it not work before?